# How to show a table in quill according to typed tags and formatted with styles

Tags: html, editor, quill, rich-text-editor, richtext

I created a custom button on Quill Editor where when clicked it shows the html tags and when clicked again it hides the tags and shows the formatting. However, I tried to write this code:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid #333;">
     <thead style="background-color: #333; color: #fff;">
         <tr>
             <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td style="border: 1px solid #333;">The table body</td>
             <td style="border: 1px solid #333;">with two columns</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Which is a simple table, and clicking the button again, the expected thing was to show a table like this:

[image]

However, the result is **empty**. How can I show this formatted table (not the tags) inside the quill? (I need to show the table like in this image I sent)

Here is my editor online to test:

https://quilleditor.netlify.app/

The source code is:

https://github.com/eltonsantos/test-quilljs-editor/blob/master/index.html

I just need that quill editor render this table according with the tags that I put on click on button.

My code is (the same as the link above):

```
// Customized icon for toggle between html tags and normal text

    icons["iphtml"] = '<i class="fa fa-sharp fa-solid fa-file-code" title="Toggle HTML"></i>';
    
    var IpHTMLClass = new Parchment.Attributor.Class("iphtml", "iphtml", {
            scope: Parchment.Scope.INLINE,
          });
          Quill.register(IpHTMLClass, true);
    
          var toolbarOptions = [
            [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
            [{ 'font': [] }],
            ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
            [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }, { 'align': [] }],
            ['link', 'image', 'video'],
            ['formula', 'code-block'],
            ['clean'],
            [{ incident: "incident" }, { iplink: "iplink" }, { iphtml: "iphtml"}],
          ]
      
          var quill = new Quill(container, {
            theme: "snow",
            modules: {
              toolbar: toolbarOptions
            },
          });
    
    quill.getModule("toolbar").addHandler("iphtml", function () {
            var content = quill.root.innerHTML;
            var isSourceMode = quill.root.dataset.sourceMode === "true";
    
            if (isSourceMode) {
              var tempElement = document.createElement("div");
              tempElement.innerHTML = content;
              quill.root.innerHTML = tempElement.textContent;
              quill.root.dataset.sourceMode = "false";
              console.log("click if")
            } else {
              quill.root.textContent = content;
              quill.root.dataset.sourceMode = "true";
              console.log("click false")
            }
          });
```